# How to build angular Project war using Apache ant build.xml

Tags: angular, apache, deployment, ant, war

```
<delete dir="${classes.dir}" />

<delete dir="${lib.dir}" />

<delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
```

```
<mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />

<mkdir dir="${lib.dir}" />

<mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
```

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}">

</javac>
```

```
<war destfile="${dist.dir}\armstrong.ant.teat.war" 

                   webxml="WebRoot/WEB-INF/web.xml">

    <classes dir="WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes"/>

    <fileset dir="${dist.dir}"/>

    <lib dir="${lib.dir}"/>

  <manifest>

    <attribute name="AntCreateWar" value="ant.Create.War" />

  </manifest>

</war>
```

```
<description>Main target</description>
```

I copied this code from(https://www.w3schools.blog/ant-create-war-file-in-eclipse ) and just changed the project Location in 3rd line , but I got error that web.xml does not exist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.